# Accessing URL parameters in Routes with Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In my routes directory for a node and Express.js web app, I have the following code:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get(htmlExt('index/:fileName'), function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.fileName);
});
```

However, `req.params.fileName` only returns the first letter of the :fileName. I have checked my code multiple times but I can't find what's wrong with this. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the `htmlExt` function look like? Do you have any other routes/middleware defined? What you've show seems correct to me, so I suspect the issue is in code not shown...

Comment: You are right, the htmlExt function was causing the error. I switched it to `router.get('index/:filename')` and it works now.

Comment: I'm still curious as to what `htmlExt` looks like that it would cause what you were seeing. Mind posting it so we can share what exactly happened?

Comment: `function htmlExt(url) {return '/' + url + '|' + url + '.html';}` ...Still not sure why this would have an effect on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here what I believe happened:

1. Start with `/index/:fileName`
2. htmlExt turned that into `/index/:fileName|index/:fileName.html`
3. Express router consumed this to create the regex `/^\/index\/([^\/]+?)|index\/([^\/]+?)\.html(?:\/(?=$))?$/i`
4. Since there's no grouping to indicate to what patterns the pipe applied, it behaved as match "either `/^\/index\/([^\/]+?)/i` *or* `/index\/([^\/]+?)\.html(?:\/(?=$))?$/i`"
5. The pattern before the pipe satisfied the expression. Since it ended in a lazy match, and `(?:\/(?=$))?$` was no longer required, it was happy to match just the first character in that match group.

I used [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester) to get an idea of what the generate regex would look like. (*note: that tool doesn't actually support the pattern matching part of the Express Router, so one little bit of fudging had to be done in my next step (I removed the escape from before the pipe)*).

I then used https://regex101.com/r/kN5kW9/1 to figure out what in tarnation was going on.

Comment: I appreciate this analysis. I will make sure to properly test/understand my regex's in the future!